# WhatsApp Cloud Api - Header & Body Template Message Php

Tags: php, whatsapp

I am trying to send a WhatsApp template message using Whatsapp Cloud API.

I am getting an error:

> Unexpected key "0" on param "template". [type]

This is the Request that I am sending via Curl Post:

```php
    "messaging_product"=> "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type" => "individual",
    "to" => "$to_number",
    "type" => "template",
    'template' => array("name"=> "templateName",'language'=>array("code"=>"en"),
    'components'=>
        array(
            array(
                "type" => "header",
                "parameters" => array(
                    array(
                        "type" => "image",
                        "image" => array(
                            "link" => $imageLink
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                "type" => "body",
                "parameters" => array(
                    array("type"=> "text","text"=> $Productid),
                )
            )
        )
   )
```

Comment: Thats not code, thats data

Comment: Where does that error come from? As a response from the API or somewhere else? It doesn't really look like a standard PHP error/warning (I could be wrong though). If it is a PHP error, then you need to post the full error message, all the relevant code (including the code that throws the error, which you also should point out). We have no clue what you do with that array.

Comment: Its a response from the Api. Not a Php error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have passed the wrong property array (that contains the `body` type) in `components` property,

It should be,

```php
array(
    'messaging_product' => "whatsapp",
    'recipient_type' => "individual",
    'to' => "$to_number",
    'type' => "template",
    'template' => array(
        'name' => "templateName",
        'language' => array( 
           'code' => "en"
        ),
        'components' => array(
            array(
                'type' => "header",
                'parameters' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => "image",
                        'image' => array(
                            'link' => $imageLink
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'type' => "body",
                'parameters' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => "text",
                        'text' => $Productid
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```